# Are Path-systems P-complete under logspace many-one reductions?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

As far as I know, the admissability of a path-system is an example of a P-complete problem.

However, I am not sure under which kind of reductions (many-one or turing-reductions? logspace or AC$^0$ reductions ... ?).

Can anyone explain me under which reductions are Path-systems P-complete, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admissible path-systems are, indeed, P-complete under many-one logspace reductions.

On the paper [1] we can see that Cook, given a Turing Machine $M$ that runs in $T(n)$ and some input $w$, builds a path-system problem that is admissible iff $M$ accepts $w$. Hence, the reduction is many-one.

The reduction is logspace, as already claimed by Cook, since it uses log(T(n)) memory, and hence, it uses k*log(n) memory if T(n) is $n^k$.

[1] Cook, Stephen A. "An observation on time-storage trade off." Proceedings of the fifth annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing. 1973.